# Jquery animate and hover

Tags: jquery, mouse, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

i'm trying to make an animation in jquery,

```
#wrapper_map div { width:94px; height:265px; float:left; cursor:pointer; position:relative;}
img.main {position: absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:10;}
img.hover {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;}

<div id="wrapper_map">
     <div class="map1"><a  href="#"><img class="main" src="1.gif" ><img class="hover" src="h_1.gif"></a></div>
    <div class="map2"><a  href="#"><img class="main" src="2.gif" ><img class="hover" src="h_2.gif"></a></div>
    <div class="map3"><a  href="#"><img class="main" src="3.gif" ><img class="hover" src="h_3.gif""></a></div>
    <div class="map4"><a  href="#"><img class="main" src="4.gif" ><img class="hover" src="h_4.gif"></a></div>
    <div class="map5"><a  href="#"><img class="main" src="5.gif" ><img class="hover" src="h_5.gif"></a></div>
</div>
```

With this function the img.hover is shown on hover. That's the first working part.

```
$("#wrapper_map img.main").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({"opacity": "0"},100);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"},100);
});
```

Now i would like to make an infinite animation :

```
Show then hide ".map1 img.hover" when it's finish,
Show then hide ".map2 img.hover" when it's finish,
Show then hide ".map3 img.hover" when it's finish,
Show then hide ".map4 img.hover" when it's finish,
Show then hide ".map5 img.hover" when it's finish, resart the animation.
```

But i need that when the mouse hover on a div (.map1, .map2 etc..) to show the img class hover of the div.
When mouse quit div wrapper_map restart the infinite animation.

I really want to do something like this, but i need help please !!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Jquery http://api.jquery.com/animate/ function has parameter complete **complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.** now for infinite animation once an animate is finished you can call another function which had animate and so on to make infinite animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```
option.imgs.filter(':visible').hide();
option.imgs.eq(index).show();
```

then control index++